# Sending an image to email via PHP

Tags: php

can you please help me with this code. i am trying to embed a image in my mail and its showing as string of alphanumeric ..

```
function send_mail_pear()
{

    $crlf = "\n";

    $to = "mail@mail.in";
    $head = ("From: mail@mail.in". "\r\n");
    $head .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $head .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg"; 

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    echo $head. "<br/>";
    $mime->setHTMLBody('<html><body><img src="map_6.gif"> <p>You see this image.</p></body></html>');
    $mime->addHTMLImage('map_6.gif', 'image/gif');  

    $subject = "Test mail";
    $mailBody = $mime->get();
    $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
    echo $mailBody ;

    /*if(mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, $head)){
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "Mail Not sent";
    }
}
```

Comment: _Where_ is it "showing" as "string of alphanumeric"? What string?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to link to the image as "cid:yourcontentid", and specify "yourcontentid" as a parameter to addHTMLImage.

You can consult [the documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addhtmlimage.php) for more information.

Comment: [You believe wrong](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addhtmlimage.php)

Comment: That would definitely work though. I am currently using this.

Comment: Just because the `addHTMLImage` feature is working for you doesn't mean providing a Content ID will magically solve whatever the OP's problem is. You get a content ID generated for you if you don't provide one yourself (it says so right there in the documentation), and either way it's unlikely to have anything to do with the encoding of the image.

Comment: 1) Could you explain your first comment please? 2) I didn't mention encoding. 3) This function does not replace `src="bla.gif"` with `src="cid:<contentid>`, so it indeed might not work.

Comment: `That would definitely work though. I am currently using this.` is a fallacy that assumes that every other factor is the same between your setups. And you didn't mention encoding, but I struggle to see what else the question could be about; the image isn't being properly encoded into the email.

Answer (score 0):

you can just attach it using. or i suggest the least painful option will be to host the image on some server and send an HTML email.

the body will look like

```
<html>
<p>
   <img src='http://yourserver.com/YOURIMAGE.gif' />
</p>
</html>
```

EDIT:

to attach images or files to an email try something like this

```
$to = "someome@anadress.com";
$from = "SOME NAME ";
$subject = "SUBJECT";
$fileatt = "./FILENAME.gif";
$fileatttype = "image/gif";
$fileattname = "ATTACHMENTNAME.gif";
$headers = "From: $from";

$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$rand}x";
$headers .= <<<HEADER
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n
boundary="{$mime_boundary}"
HEADER;

$message = <<<MESSAGE
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n
-{$mime_boundary}\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1"\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n
\n\n
–{$mime_boundary}\n
Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n
name="{$fileattname}"\n
Content-Disposition: attachment;\n
filename="{$fileattname}"\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n
{$data}\n\n
-{$mime_boundary}-\n
MESSAGE;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo "The email was sent.";
}
else {
  echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```

Comment: Your explanation of how to attach it is missing.

Comment: There is no need to handle the mime part yourself, that is probably the reason the OP is using Mail_Mime.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Matthias Vance is part of the story.

If you want to send a self-contained HTML mail, then it needs to be sent as an [mhtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) type (NB the content type for this varies on different implementations - it should be multipart/related but frequently is message/rfc822). There is however a formal definition of the structure in [RFC 2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557). Each of the components should be a seperate attachment. This also means that each URL has to be rewritten to use a local reference and the cid scheme - IIRC, the PEAR class does not do this for you.

There is some documentation on the net e.g. [this one](http://www.phpied.com/the-proper-mhtml-syntax/) - but do not fall into the trap of believing this is suitable for anything other than sending emails / saving web pages locally - MSIE does not handle mhtml files delivered over HTTP correctly.

I'm not aware of any off the shelf package for generating mhtml files / emails - but there are some for [parsing such files](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4570-PHP-Parse-and-extract-files-from-MIME-HTML-archives.html). Writing a tool to do this would be straightforward but not trivial.

Comment: You can perfectly do this yourself, just supply the cid in the function (I believe there is also a function that allows you to get the cid of the attachment you just added), and rewrite the link.